# Magento Product Create Issue - SOAP V2

Tags: magento-1.5.1

I am trying to create products using Magento V2 SOAP(WSI) from a Java web service client. Product seems to be created so as the stock data. However, the created produce doesn't link up with the Main Web Site Store, and the relevant category. Also I have filled up some additional attributes but those too seems to be not updated. I was wondering whether there is any problem with configurations. Magento version is 1.5.1.0 and the site has be configured with the sample data.

Thanks in advance for your help to identify the issue.

Here is the sample request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urn:catalogProductCreateRequestParam xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
    <sessionId/>
    <type>simple</type>
    <set>38</set>
    <sku>phone207_sku</sku>
    <productData>
        <name>Phone 207</name>
        <description>Phone Description</description>
        <short_description>Phone Short Description</short_description>
        <weight>10</weight>
        <status>1</status>
        <visibility>4</visibility>
        <category_ids>
            <complexObjectArray>8</complexObjectArray>
        </category_ids>
        <website_ids>
            <complexObjectArray>1</complexObjectArray>
        </website_ids>
        <price>100</price>
        <tax_class_id>1</tax_class_id>
        <additional_attributes>
            <complexObjectArray>
                <key>model</key>
                <value>n2011</value>
            </complexObjectArray>
            <complexObjectArray>
                <key>in_depth</key>
                <value>Description In Depth</value>
            </complexObjectArray>
        </additional_attributes>
        <stock_data>
            <qty>10</qty>
            <is_in_stock>1</is_in_stock>
            <manage_stock>1</manage_stock>
        </stock_data>
    </productData>
</urn:catalogProductCreateRequestParam>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about this but the odd things I see in your xml are

```
    <category_ids>
        <complexObjectArray>8</complexObjectArray>
    </category_ids>
    <website_ids>
        <complexObjectArray>1</complexObjectArray>
    </website_ids>
```

The category and website ids are declared as `complexObjectArray` but contain numerical values.

Also in the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Api_V2::_prepareDataForSave` method, that is's involved in creating a product there is this:

```
    if (property_exists($productData, 'categories') && is_array($productData->categories)) {
        $product->setCategoryIds($productData->categories);
    }

    if (property_exists($productData, 'websites') && is_array($productData->websites)) {
        foreach ($productData->websites as &$website) {
            if (is_string($website)) {
                try {
                    $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite($website)->getId();
                } catch (Exception $e) { }
            }
        }
        $product->setWebsiteIds($productData->websites);
    }
```

So Magento looks for `categories` and `websites` not `category_ids` and `website_ids`.